# Can Latex use .xps format file?

Tags: includegraphics

Can I include graphics file with .xps format?

When I try to do it, it comes to error.

Let me describe the whole story.

I use AutoCAD to draw all graphics, then print them to graphics file with .png or .jpg file, but the resolution and the file size is so bad, and I cannot understand why Autodesk Inc. is so poor in print to graphic files.

Hence I try to print graphics to other format, I try to use Default Windows System Printer, and it comes out .xps or oxps file. I am satisfied the resolution, but I don't know how to be included in Latex.

If I remembered well, about 20 years ago, Default Windows System Printer came out .eps file, which can be used in Latex. Time has changed.

Any suggestion?

John

Comment: LaTeX can include PDF-files, so if you can print to PDF that is an option.

Comment: [This page](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad-lt/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2019/ENU/AutoCAD-LT/files/GUID-A72DB257-3410-4792-B548-6B9FC1DED72B-htm.html) suggests you can still export from AutoCAD to EPS file format. Isn't it an option?

Comment: @Ivan gives me a good solution, PDF-files is not good as EPS-files,PDF file has large size. Thanks to both.

Comment: if you are including into a pdf made with pdflatex it will need to be converted to pdf anyway, so the size of the eps file is not that relevant what you want to compare is the pdf directly made against the pdf  converted from the eps by epstopdf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [export](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad-lt/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2019/ENU/AutoCAD-LT/files/GUID-A72DB257-3410-4792-B548-6B9FC1DED72B-htm.html) from AutoCAD to EPS file format.

Comment: I would accept @Ivan's answer.  It seems there are two ways to get EPS file, but both are not satisfied. 1st way export the WHOLE windows to EPS file; 2nd way PRINT an EPS file which size are fixed such as A4 paper. What I want is an EPS with FREE size I can set myself.  Therefore I have to edit above EPS file.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `.xps` to `.pdf` with `xpstopdf` from `libgxps-utils` in Linux.